# how do I cahin logical CMake Generators?

Tags: cmake

Logically I want to do something like this in my cmake build (given in pseudo C++)

`exceptions_flag = 
    Compiler == Clang || Compiler == GCC ? "-fexceptions"
  : Compiler == MSVC ? "/U_HAS_EXCEPTIONS;/D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=1;/EHsc"`

I'm not sure how to do this in one step with cmake generators the best I can think of is

`set(EXCEPTIONS_FLAG 
$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:"/U_HAS_EXCEPTIONS;/D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=1;/EHsc">
if(NOT ${EXCEPTIONS_FLAG})
  set(EXCEPTIONS_FLAG "-fexceptions")
endif()`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can't you go with just `if(MSVC) ... else() ... endif()`?

Comment: Yes, but I have a lot of these sorts of things and I'd rather not deal with half-initialized variables if I don't have to.

Comment: `set(VAR default)` and then `if(MSVC) set(VAR ...) endif()`.